# how does malloc work in details?

Tags: memory, malloc

I am trying to find some useful information on the malloc function.
when I call this function it allocates memory dynamically. it returns the pointer (e.g. the address) to the beginning of the allocated memory. 
**the questions:**

- how the returned address is used in order to read/write into the allocated memory block (using inderect addressing registers or how?)
- if it is not possible to allocate a block of memory it returns NULL. what is NULL in terms of hardware?
- in order to allocate memory in heap we need to know which memory parts are occupied. where this information (about the occupied memory) is stored (if for example we use a small risc microcontroller)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Q3 The usual way that heaps are managed are through a linked list.  In the simplest case, the malloc function retains a pointer to the first free-space block in the heap, and each free-space block has a header that points to the next free space block in the heap.  So the heap is in-effect self-defining in terms of knowing what is not occupied (and by inference what is therefore occupied); this minimizes the amount of overhead RAM needed to manage the heap.

When new space is needed via a malloc call, a large enough free-space block is found by traversing the linked list.  That found free-space block is given to the malloc caller (with a small hidden header), and if needed a smaller free-space block is inserted into the linked list with any residual space between the original free space block and how much memory the malloc call asked for.

When a heap block is released by the application, its block is just formatted with the linked-list header, and added to the linked list, usually with some extra logic to combine consecutive free-space blocks into one larger free-space block.

Debugging versions of malloc usually do more, including retaining linked-lists of the allocated areas too, "guard zones" around the allocated heap areas to help detect memory overflows, etc.  These take up extra heap space (making the heap effectively smaller in terms of usable space for the applications), but are extremely helpful when debugging.

Q2 A NULL pointer is effectively just a zero, which if used attempts to access memory starting at location 0 of RAM, which is almost always reserved memory of the OS.  This is the cause of a significant quantity of memory violation aborts, all caused by programmer's lack of error checking for NULL returns from functions that allocate memory).

Because accessing memory location 0 by a non-OS application is never what is wanted, most hardware aborts any attempt to access location 0 by non-OS software. Even with page mapping such that the applications memory space (including location 0) is never mapped to real RAM location 0, since NULL is always zero, most CPUs will still abort attempts to access location 0 on the assumption that this is an access via a pointer that contains NULL.

Given your RISC processor, you will need to read its documentation to see how it handles attempts to access memory location 0.

Q1 There are many high-level language ways to use allocated memory, primarily through pointers, strings, and arrays.

In terms of assembly language and the hardware itself, the allocated heap block address just gets put into a register that is being used for memory indirection.  You will need to see how that is handled in the RISC processor.  However if you use C or C++ or such higher level language, then you don't need to worry about registers; the compiler handles all that.

Answer (score -1):

Since you are using malloc, can we assume  you are using C?
If so, you assign the result to a pointer variable, then you can access the memory by referencing through the variable.   You don't really know how this is implemented in assembly.  That depends on CPU  you are using.  malloc return 0 if it fails.  Since usually NULL is defined as 0,  you can test for NULL.   You don't care how malloc tracks the free memory.  If you really need this information, you should look at the source in glibc/malloc available on the net

```
char * c = malloc(10);   // allocate 10 bytes
if (c == NULL)
   // handle error case
else
   *c = 'a'  // write a in the first character on the block
```